# Spring Boot + Spring Security - Frontend encryption for sensitive data

Tags: javascript, spring, security, encryption, frontend

Just curious, if I wanted to encrypt the sensitive data (e.g password) entered by the user AT THE FRONTEND, perhaps using RSA algo, before transmitted out to the backend, does Spring Boot or Spring Security provides any helper for this?
Or we need to manually add the relevant javascript encryption library at the frontend code and code it manually?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37701116/sending-password-safely-from-the-front-end-to-the-back-end-using-md5 this will answer your question

Comment: HTTPS provides protection for data exchange between client and server. Do you need encryption for anything else like storage of data on non-trusted cloud platform? Please also read this http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have the impression that it is always safer to encrypt the sensitive data at application layer as well, in addition to the transport layer (ssl). Nevertheless putting aside whether if there is really a need for frontend encryption at application layer if we are already using SSL, my question is more of focus on whether Spring provides any feature to make implementing frontend encryption at app layer easy for us or not.  My query is more on trying to understand more about spring boot +spring security.